# How to get TextAngular to compile its content?

Tags: angularjs, textangular

I would like to pass strings into `textAngular` so that $scope properties are compiled For example

```
$scope.text = "Hey {{person.name}}";
```

Then in the HTML I have

```
 <div text-angular ng-model="text"></div>
```

Temporarily I put together a hack for my controller.

```
$scope.$watch(function(){return $scope.text;}, function(html) {
        $scope.text = $interpolate($scope.text)($scope);
});
```

How do I turn this hack into a directive that plays nice with textAngular?

Comment: can you not interpolate it once inside callback when it is received and get rid of `$watch`?

Comment: @charlietfl I dont understand. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Show where `$scope.text` gets called from server. Can't you just interpolate it in that callback? Not really sure how your template system in the editor is supposed to work also

Comment: I could do that, but then when the $scope value changes the text is not updated.

Comment: again...it is not very clear how you are trying to use this. My assumption from trivial example given was you only wanted to set it once when loaded

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you should be doing is this:

```
$scope.text = "Hey "+$scope.person.name;
```

Realistically once you put the text in the ngModel, the user can change the text.

Comment: Thats not an option. I am returning the string from the server.

Comment: Ok, then perhaps just set the value of $scope.text after you have successfully retrieved the value from the server?